# CoffeeScript curiousity about splat & this implementation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So, looking thru some code with functional & currying as a driver of it.. I am seeing this convention of splat usage, and though I can "see" what it is doing in the compiled javascript, I have not seen ANY mention of this is docs etc.. on the "..." splat usage for coffeescript at the end of the line (see below).

For instance, we have:

```
flip = (f) -> (as...) -> f as.reverse()...
```

which compiles to:

```
flip = function(f) {
  return function() {
    var as;
    as = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
    return f.apply(null, as.reverse());
  };
};
```

Now, I understand that "as..." is being used as:

```
as = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
```

taking the arguments and assigning them to "as".

BUT, what I am not wrapping my head around is this usage here:

```
 -> f as.reverse()...  # <-- the "..." at the end.
```

If I remove it (the '...'), then the "apply" of the compiled goes away.. SO, what is the convention here of using "..." at the end. I am missing this concept in my coffeescript knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about `...` being at the end of the line.

What you see here is the difference between a splat parameter and a splat argument. The `...` operator is used for both cases because they are related. It may be confusing, though, since these uses are inverses of each other.

`as.reverse()...` is a splat argument passed to `f`. The compiled JavaScript uses `f.apply` to break `as.reverse()` into multiple arguments for the receiver `f`.

`as...` is a splat parameter. The compiled JavaScript uses `__slice` to convert the `arguments` object into an array inside the receiver, to collect the arguments into a single list.

Comment: I see what you are saying, as "as....reverse()" wouldn't make sense, but since it is a splat, wouldn't the coffeescript be smart enough to not need the a.reverse()... - at the end? I "thought" as was assigned the arguments, so that is why I am a little confused as to the need for the "..." at the end.

Comment: @jamesemanon It's only a coincidence that we get `as` from a splat parameter so close to the place where we do `f as.reverse()...`. `reverse` is a function on JavaScript arrays, so we use a splat parameter (`as...`) to create the array `as`, then we call `reverse()` to create a new array, and we break that new array apart using a splat argument (all of which is compactly described by `f as.reverse()...`). We need to break the new array apart because, in general, `f` is not expecting an array argument.